# PG::SyntaxError: ERROR: syntax error at or near

Tags: ruby, postgresql

I am trying to connect directly to a postgres database and run a query. It tells me the table, which is a view does not exist, but  I see it listed.  What am I missing?

## Code

```
require 'pg'
conn = PG::Connection.open(:dbname => 'mydatabase')

conn.exec("Select * From Distinct_filing_xml_view")
```

## ERROR

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "distinct_filing_view" does not exist
LINE 1: Select * From Distinct_filing_xml_view
                      ^

    from (irb):5:in `exec'
    from (irb):5
    from /Users/aa/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

## Tables

```
res= conn.exec("select table_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.views")
res.each {|i| puts i }
{"table_name"=>"Max_filing_xml_view"}
{"table_name"=>"Distinct_filing_xml_view"}
{"table_name"=>"Filing_xml_view"}
{"table_name"=>"select_in_max_subdate_view"}
{"table_name"=>"max_sub_date"}
```

## Update: Found Solution

```
res = conn.exec('Select * From "Distinct_filing_xml_view"')
```

Does anyone know why the quotes are needed?

Comment: You've discovered Postgres is case sensitive. MySQL, if you're used to that, doesn't *always* care, much to the consternation of many a DBA.

Comment: You or tool you used must have created those relations using _quoted identifier_ with makes them case sensitive. Normally identifiers are converted to lower case. As for MySQL, by default  - case sensitive for Unix and case insensitive for Windows (+ kinda OS X).

Comment: I only have three tables, is there a way to alter them to make them non-case insensitive? I'm on OS X and Postgres 9.6.1.0

Comment: Try it with a migration: `$ rails g migration ChangeTableName`, then inside migration file add rename_table method `rename_table "Distinct_filing_xml_view", "distinct_filing_xml_view"`